# Python adding extra backslash in list

Tags: python, list

The issue is when we pass the list to subprocess.Popen command.
Normally python removes the extra slash but not in case of subprocess.Popen.

I have created a list in python and adding a variable.

```
var1='--username=domain\username'
ls=[]
ls.append(var1)
print(ls)
```

output:

```
['--username=domain\\username']
```

i don't want this extra backslash in the list because when i am passing list to the subprocess.Popen module, it is having problem reading the username.

Comment: There is no extra backslash in that list.  The standard string representation of a list is built from the `repr()` of its elements, which in the case of strings means showing them in the form of a Python string literal.

Comment: @jasonharper
When we pass the list to Subprocess.Popen, it causes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

The extra backslash is appearing because the code is setting the variable equal to a string literal. It's an escape character for that slash used in how it's represented.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/str-vs-repr-in-python/

The following code might help in understanding what's going on in your example:

```
var1='--username=domain\username'
ls=[]
ls.append(var1)
print(ls)
print(ls[0]) # the contents of the string literal
print(ls[0][16])
print(ls[0][17]) # only one slash after all
print(ls[0][18])
```

Comment: I will try to implement your solution. For the time being i have for solution. I am hard coding the single slash.
When we print each element via for loop also we don't get slash but when it passes it to Subprocess.Popen it causes issue.